# Subaru legacy 2021

Tags: battery, starting, subaru, legacy

2021 subaru legacy will start with jumper cables I let it idle for a half an hour then shut it of and when I went to try and start it that I only getting a clicking noise. Also when I try to start vehicle lights are good and navigational screen comes on fine

Comment: When you get the clicking noise, do the lights turn off or get dim? Click the comment link below to reply.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the battery is at fault here. Take it to a store which can do a load test on it (anywhere which sells batteries can most likely do this for you). Most batteries have a life expectancy of around five years. If yours is anywhere close or older than this, it's pretty much a done deal.